# Calculate probability function

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I would like to calculate the following with *Mathematica*:

> Let $X$ be a random variable with probability function
>   $$p(x)= \left\{ \begin{matrix}
> \frac{x}{6} & \text{for }x \in \{1,2,3\}\\
> 0 & \text{Otherwise}
> \end{matrix}\right.
> $$ 
>   Calculate $P(X \leq 2)$, $E(X)$ and $var(x)$

My major problem is to create the probability function with the correct distribution since there haven't been any specific distribution informed in the task. So how do I solve this?

If it is any help, then the results are respectively:

```
{0.5, 2.333, 0.5556}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can done as follows (consistent with your own definition):

```
p=ProbabilityDistribution[x/6, {x, 1, 3, 1}]
```

This is discrete PMF using your definition.
The PMF definition can be displayed:

```
PDF[p, x]
```

Your questions follow:

```
{Probability[x <= 2, x \[Distributed] p], Mean[p], Variance[p]}
```

yields:

```
{1/2, 7/3, 5/9}
```

or numerically:

```
N@{Probability[x <= 2, x \[Distributed] p], Mean[p], Variance[p]}
```

yielding:

```
{0.5, 2.33333, 0.555556}
```

Comment: Noting the relative ease to calculate: P(X<=2)=1/6+2/6=1/2; E[x]-1/6+2 x 2/6+ 3 x 3/6=14/6=7/3 and similarly variance E[x^2]-E[x]^2

Answer (score 6):

You could also use `EmpiricalDistribution`:

```
In[1]:= di = EmpiricalDistribution[{1, 2, 3}/6 -> {1, 2, 3}];

In[2]:= {Mean[di], Variance[di], CDF[di, 2]}

Out[2]= {7/3, 5/9, 1/2}

In[3]:= N[%]

Out[3]= {2.33333, 0.555556, 0.5}
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know the function EmpiricalDistribution...
With the setup you have created, how would you calculate eg. $P(X_1+X_2 \leq 2)$ ?

Comment: Assuming you mean that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent and identically distributed, I would do `Probability[x1 + x2 <= 2, {Distributed[x1, di], Distributed[x2, di]}]` which yields $\frac{1}{36}$.

Comment: Does this work for mms 8 as well? Because it can't calculate it when I try.

Comment: I was using version 9.

Answer (score 5):

```
d = ProbabilityDistribution[
  Piecewise[{{x/6, x == 1 || x == 2 || x == 3}}, 0], {x, 0, 10, 1}]

Grid[{{DiscretePlot[Evaluate[PDF[d, x]], {x, 0, 10}, 
    PlotLabel -> "PDF", ExtentSize -> 0.5, 
    PlotStyle -> ColorData[1, 1]],
   DiscretePlot[Evaluate[CDF[d, x]], {x, 0, 10}, PlotLabel -> "CDF", 
    ExtentSize -> Right, PlotStyle -> ColorData[1, 1]]}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Mean[d] // N
(*2.33333333333333*)

Variance[d] // N
(*0.555555555555556*)

Probability[x <= 2 , x \[Distributed] d] // N
(*0.5*)

Expectation[x, x \[Distributed] d] // N
(*2.33333333333333*)
```